# passing dynamic form values and span id values via ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

hi amazing stackoverflows. i have a form that performs calculations  for dynamic form values via ajax.the form input values gets submitted while the span div value does not. can someone help me. thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#orderForm").on('submit',(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

url: "order.php",

            type: "POST",

        data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
            $("#target").html(data);
$('#alerts').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});


</script>




<form method="post"  id="orderForm">
 price:<input  type="text" name="price[]"  value=""><br>
sum total:  <span id="sum">500</span>

</form>
```

Comment: what is sum total mean in your form

Comment: the sum total is automatically generated based on price inputed. the value 500 in the span is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a hidden input field to your form, in addition to the span.
Like so:

```
<form method="post"  id="orderForm">
   <input type="hidden" id="sum">
   price:<input  type="text" name="price[]"  value=""><br>
   sum total:  <span id="sum">500</span>
</form>
```

Comment: it is not advised to have two DOM objects with the same id !!

Comment: it is not advisable to have a span tag act as an input box :). just saying.